# How to enable ANSI escape codes in Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, color, ansi

What is the simplest way to enable [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (eg. colored output) in Windows cmd?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CMD` does not support ANSI escape sequences. You'll have to use `COMMAND.COM`. What is it that you're trying to do?

[How to Enable ANSI.SYS in a Command Window](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101875) (for COMMAND.COM)

[How to Use ANSI.SYS in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100394) (for COMMAND.COM)

**Edit:**

You can get [`less` for Windows](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html#binaries) and use:

```
less -R filename
```

Comment: I'm trying to view Rails log files that use ANSI codes for colored output

Answer (score 2):

You might try Cygwin's bash. Terminal colorization is something that Just Works under Cygwin.